# Refreshing image every second only if its fully available

Tags: javascript, php

I am running into some problems. I want to grap an live image over http and save it on my webserver. With javascript I am refreshing the saved image every second. But when javascript is refreshing and the image is not fully saved, I only see the half image (not fully loaded image).

Is there a method to handle this? eg. only display the image when the save task is complete? if not show the old "cached" image till a new one is available.

My php file to access the image from source:

```
$path = realpath(dirname(__FILE__));
for ($i = 0; $i < 59; ++$i) {
    copy('http://<<<IP>>>/livepicture.jpg', $path.'/livepicture.jpg');
    sleep(1);
}
```

My html file refreshing the image:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" >
function ChangeMedia(){
    var d = new Date();
    var t = d.getTime();
    document.getElementById('camara').src = "livepicture.jpg?"+t;
}
var reloadcam = setInterval("ChangeMedia()",1000);
</script>
<img src="livepicture.jpg" alt="Loading..." name="camara" id="camara" />
```

Comment: you need `onload` event of image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify the following code to copy the image file and only after it has downloaded replace the previous file.

```
$path = realpath(dirname(__FILE__));
for ($i = 0; $i < 59; ++$i) {
    copy('http://<<<IP>>>/livepicture.jpg', $path.'/temp.jpg');
    rename($path.'/temp.jpg', $path.'/livepicture.jpg');
    sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: after the for loop is finished i get an 500 error. do you know why?

Comment: I know what was the problem (error 500): The default time for scripts to run was set to 60 seconds inside the php settings. The for loop in the answer is of course running longer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with ajax requet and onload event of image and when your php response good Refresh the page